# PostgreSQL How to check if my function is still running

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Just a quick question .

I have one heavy function in PostgreSQL 9.3 , how I can check if the function is still running after several hours and how to run a function in background in psql ( my connection is unstable from time to time)

Thanks

Comment: Check out `pg_stat_activity`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW

Answer (score 4):

For long running functions, it can be useful to have them `RAISE LOG` or `RAISE NOTICE` from time to time, indicating progress. If they're looping over millions of records, you might emit a log message every few thousand records.

Some people also (ab)use a `SEQUENCE`, where they get the `nextval` of the sequence in their function, and then directly read the sequence value to check progress. This is crude but effective. I prefer logging whenever possible.

To deal with disconnects, run `psql` on the remote side over ssh rather than connecting to the server directly over the PostgreSQL protocol. As Christian suggests, use `screen` so the remote `psql` doesn't get killed when the ssh session dies.

Alternately, you can use the traditional unix command `nohup`, which is available everywhere:

```
nohup psql -f the_script.sql </dev/null &
```

which will run `psql` in the background, writing all output and errors to a file named `nohup.out`.

You may also find that if you enable TCP keepalives, you don't lose remote connections anyway.

Comment: Wont `psql` be killed by `SIGHUP` when the remote connection dies?

Comment: Nope, not in bash if it's backgrounded, as background jobs go in a different process group. In other shells you may need `nohup`.

Comment: Er... or not. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Login to the psql console.

```
$ psql -U user -d database
```

2- Issue a `\x` command to format the results.

3- `SELECT * from pg_stat_activity;`

4- Scroll until you see your function name on the list. It should have an **active** status.

5- Check if there are any blocks on the table that your function relies on using:

```
SELECT k_locks.pid AS pid_blocking, k_activity.usename AS user_blocking, k_activity.query AS query_blocking, locks.pid AS pid_blocked, activity.usename AS user_blocked, activity.query AS query_blocked, to_char(age(now(), activity.query_start), 'HH24h:MIm:SSs') AS blocking_age FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks locks JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity activity ON locks.pid = activity.pid JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks k_locks ON locks.locktype = k_locks.locktype and locks.database is not distinct from k_locks.database and locks.relation is not distinct   from   k_locks.relation          and locks.page is not distinct   from   k_locks.page          and locks.tuple is not distinct   from   k_locks.tuple          and locks.virtualxid is not distinct   from   k_locks.virtualxid          and locks.transactionid is not distinct   from   k_locks.transactionid          and locks.classid is not distinct   from   k_locks.classid          and locks.objid is not distinct   from   k_locks.objid          and locks.objsubid is not distinct   from   k_locks.objsubid          and locks.pid <> k_locks.pid    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity k_activity               ON k_locks.pid = k_activity.pid    WHERE   k_locks.granted         and not locks.granted    ORDER BY   activity.query_start;
```

Answer (score 1):

`pg_stat_activity` is a good hint to check if your function is still running. Also use `screen` or `tmux` on the server to ensure that it will survive a reconnect.